# why does useReducer run twice?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i have a problem.
im creating a shop cart using react js.
i have a component called Header and a component for contextProvider. in contextProvider i have a useReducer.
my problem is with these two components. when i click on a product, it normally add just one product to cart. it is ok and i want this. but the problem is here that when i click on cart icon, a modal card will be on screen and if i close that modal card them add a product to cart, the product will be added to cart two times!! i know what line of code cause this error but i dont know why it happens! the problem is with the state in Header component. if i remove and add that in context component, it will work normally. but why?? if you need anything else with my codes, tell me. here is my codes:
my context:

```
        import React, { useReducer, useState } from "react";

const Context = React.createContext({
  allAddedToCart: 0,
  productsList: [],
  addToCart: () => {},
  initializeProductList: (product) => {},
/*   open: false,
  setOpen: (open) => {}, */
});

export const ContextProvider = (props) => {
/* const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); */
  const [productsState, dispatchProducts] = useReducer(
    (prevState, action) => {
      if (action.type === "add_to_cart") {
        prevState.products_list.forEach((element, index) => {
          console.log(index);
          if (element.id === action.id) {
            element.number++;
            element.allPrice += element.price;
            console.log("finished");
          }
        });
        return {
          allAddedToCart: prevState.allAddedToCart + 1,
          products_list: prevState.products_list,
        };
      } else if (action.type === "initialize_list") {
        return {
          allAddedToCart: prevState.allAddedToCart,
          products_list: [...prevState.products_list, action.product],
        };
      }
    },
    {
      allAddedToCart: 0,
      products_list: [],
    }
  );
  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        allAddedToCart: productsState.allAddedToCart,
        productsList: productsState.products_list,
        addToCart: (id) => {
          console.log("add me to the cart");
          dispatchProducts({ type: "add_to_cart", id: id });
        },
        initializeProductList: (product) => {
          dispatchProducts({ type: "initialize_list", product: product });
        },
/*         open: open,
        setOpen: (open) => {
          setOpen(open);
        } */
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default Context;
```

my Header component:

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Context from "../context/context";
import styles from "../styles/Header.module.css";
import CartModal from "./CartModal";

const Header = (props) => {
    const ctx = useContext(Context)
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
      {open ? ReactDOM.createPortal(<CartModal close={() => {setOpen(false)}} />, document.getElementById("modal_place")) : ""}
      <h1 className={styles.title}>a react shopping cart project</h1>
      <a href="/" onClick={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); setOpen(true)}}>
        <i className={`fas fa-shopping-cart ${styles.cart}`}></i>
        <span className={styles.added_products_number}>{ctx.allAddedToCart}</span>
      </a>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

On the add_to_cart dispatch, on that first return try changing the product's list from

```
products_list: prevState.products_list
```

to

```
products_list:[...prevState.products_list]
```

Comment: If i close the cart and if i add nothing it stay the same and if i add a product, it will be updated and as i said, after closing the modal, if i add just one product that product will be added to cart for two times and after the first product, adding a product will be normally before another openning the modal. I hope you undestood. So actully, after each openning and closing the modal, it happen just once.